# Regular expression in Python two letters preceding and succeeding different letter

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following regular expression I need to produce in Python:

The set of all strings out of the alphabet {a,b} such that each a is preceded and followed by 2 b's. Below I have produced valid strigns of length 0 to 4

Valid strings: [empty string], b, bb, bbb, bbbb, bbab, etc.

Invalid Strings: a, ba, ab, bba, bbab

My reg expression is currently: "(b|bbabb)+" and it's matching everything except empty string, but since I would like to support empty string, I replaced the "+" with "*", and now for some reason that is producing a match for every string from 1 to 4(I only tested up to length 4 so far) of this alphabet. It gives matches for:

{a, b, aa, bb, ab, ba, aaa, bbb, etc..} even though it should fail for any string that has a where each a is not preceded by 2 b's and that is not followed by 2 b's

```
def alphaf():
    return "(b|bbabb)*"



regex = alphaf()


p = re.compile(regex)
#Below are the test strings

test = 'a'
match = p.match(test)
if match is None:
    print('No Match: {0}'.format(test))
else:
    print('Match: {0}'.format(test))

test = 'b'
match = p.match(test)
if match is None:
    print('No Match: {0}'.format(test))
else:
    print('Match: {0}'.format(test))

test = 'bbabb'
match = p.match(test)
if match is None:
    print('No Match: {0}'.format(test))
else:
    print('Match: {0}'.format(test))

test = 'abb'
match = p.match(test)
if match is None:
    print('No Match: {0}'.format(test))
else:
    print('Match: {0}'.format(test))

test = 'bba'
match = p.match(test)
if match is None:
    print('No Match: {0}'.format(test))
else:
    print('Match: {0}'.format(test))

test = 'bbbab'
match = p.match(test)
if match is None:
    print('No Match: {0}'.format(test))
else:
    print('Match: {0}'.format(test))

test = 'bbbabb'
match = p.match(test)
if match is None:
    print('No Match: {0}'.format(test))
else:
    print('Match: {0}'.format(test))

test = ''
match = p.match(test)
if match is None:
    print('No Match: {0}'.format(test))
else:
    print('Match: {0}'.format(test))
```

Comment: What you have is just a "raw string", not anything that will do a regular expression search. Surely this cannot be your entire code since a `return` must be within a function. Also, I am not sure you are giving us the complete problem description. Is it something like: "Given a list if strings (or a multiline string), return those strings (or lines) that contain an `a` that is followed and preceded by two `b`'s? Or something similar?

Comment: Yea that is exactly it I just need to produce the regex that produces that and thanks for noticing that I will change it. And yea basically if there is an “a” it needs to be surrounded by two “b’s” in front and back

Comment: Update your question and show more work (this is why you are getting downvoted).

Comment: Okay I got back asap. I updated the question. So I removed the 'r' and it got everything working except the empty string, but when I replace the "+" with kleenee star, now it matches every single string even 'a', even though 'a' is not in the group: (b|bbabb)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using raw strings. Run Python and when you get the `>>>` prompt, enter `'\n'` and `r'\n'` and see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex should be: `^(b*((?<=bb)a(?=bb))?)+$`:

1. `^` Matches the start of the string. Technically this is not required since the `match` function forces the match to begin at the beginning of the string (unlike the `search` function).
2. `b*` Matches 0 or more `b` characters.
3. `((?<=bb)a(?=bb))?` is an optional group that matches an `a` if if is preceded by two `b` characters and followed by two `b` characters.
4. `+` Items 2. and 3., which might match, for example, `bbb` or `bbba` (if the latter is followed by `bb`) may be repeated multiple times.
5. '$' Matches the end of the string.

[See Demo](http://ideone.com/JVc1Kt)

**Some further explanations:**

In my regex, an empty string (`b*`) multiple times (`+`) is still an empty string, that is `b*b*` still  matches an empty string. So there is no problem there.

In your regex, when you have the pattern `bbabb+` (`bbabb` multiple times) and the string `bbabbabb`, the first time you will first match `bbabb`. But that leaves left `abb` unmatched in the input string for the next match. But when you try to do the next match you can't match the pattern `bbabb` against `abb`. Your pattern would only work for strings that are exactly like `bbabbbbabbbbabbbbabb`, that is, strings `bbabb` concatenated together.

My regex on each repetition of the `+` operator just matches a string of `b` characters and optionaly an `a` if it is preceded by two `b` characters (this is the *lookbehind* test: `(?<=bb)`) and followed by two `b` characters (this is the *lookahead* test: `(?=bb)`). But it does not actually match the following two `b` characters. It leaves those characters in the string unmatched for the next repetition of `+`.

So given the string `bbabbabb` and my regex, each repetition of the `+` operator matches successively the following substrings:

- bba (matched `b*a?` because the lookbehind and lookahead conditions for `a?` were satisfied)
- bba (matched `b*a?` because the lookbehind and lookahead conditions for `a?` were satisfied)
- bb (could not find following optional `a`)

Comment: No sorry I didn't explain properly. First it doesn't accept empty string(my mistake from the instructions). 2. It accepts more than just 'bbabb', basically it is as follows. It can have any number of b's. The only restriction on what you do is placed on an 'a'. If there is an 'a', there needs to be two b's in front and behind it. So long as those 2 conditions hold, the string is valid.

Valid strings ex: 'b', 'bbbbbabb', bbabbbbb'. Invalid: 'a', 'ba', 'ab', 'abb'. They are invalid because each a does not have 2 b's on both sides of each 'a'.

Thank you and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have revised my answer based on your latest comment. I assume that `bbbabbbabb` is a valid string.

Comment: Why doesn't b* conflict with the '+' on the outside of the expression? Wouldn't that leave possibility of empty string? I guess I'm not understanding how the order works. I thought (b+|bbabb+)+ would be described as follows: The outside plus makes you choose either part of the group, so for string of length 1, you pick 'b', now since + allows you to add again, you can pick another 'b' to produce 'bb', or you can pick 'bbbabb'(bbabb got added on to the initial b from string length 1). With that expression wouldn't it support every string in the language? Any # of b's and it restricts a's.

Comment: I updated the answer with some further explanations.